Get all tax rates within a given date range
I have a table with tax rates. Each tax rate has two date fields: 'valid_from' and 'valid_to'. 'valid_to' can be NULL, then the tax rate is valid until a later tax rate is inserted. Now I want to determine all tax rates valid in a given period with :start_date and :end_date. The problem is that a tax rate without 'valid_to' is valid, viewed individually, as long as its valid_from is not after the given period. So I have to take into account whether such tax rates have been replaced by later tax rates. But it can also be the case that a tax rate with valid_to = NULL falls in part of the given period and then a new tax rate takes over the next part of the period.
My approach still has problems with this:
SELECT *
FROM taxes t1
WHERE 
    t1.valid_from <= '2024-12-31'
    AND (t1.valid_to >= '2022-07-01' OR t1.valid_to IS NULL)
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM taxes t2
        WHERE t2.valid_from > t1.valid_from
          AND t2.valid_from <= '2024-12-31'
          AND (t2.valid_to IS NULL OR t2.valid_to > '2022-07-01')
          AND t2.valid_from <= IFNULL(t1.valid_to, '2024-12-31')
    );

CREATE TABLE `taxes` (
  `valid_from` date NOT NULL,
  `valid_to` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `rate` decimal(4,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `taxes` (`valid_from`, `valid_to`, `rate`) VALUES
('2022-01-01', '2022-12-31', 10.00),
('2023-01-01', NULL, 12.00),
('2024-07-01', NULL, 15.00);

ALTER TABLE `taxes`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY `valid_from` (`valid_from`);
COMMIT;


Expected result is all three rows, but the valid_from = '2023-01-01' is missing

Please add table description , show create table taxes , add some data example and expected result , all in text format

@Ergest Basha: Done

Why valid_from is defined as NOT NULL and UNIQUE but not PRIMARY KEY? According index will be clustered anycase.

@Akina: Changed it to primary key.

Why are you taking dates t1.valid_from <= '2024-12-31' AND (t1.valid_to >= '2022-07-01'? Is the tax rate being considered 6-monthly basis? Please help me understand your requirement in case its a 6 monthly and there are multiple taxes applicable then we need to consider only the latest one?

@SharadPaul These are not real tax rates, just for testing. But there were, for example, six-month tax cuts during Covid.

For MySQL versions < 8.0 you could use a correlated subquery,
SELECT valid_from,
       valid_to,
       rate 
FROM ( SELECT  t.valid_from,
               COALESCE( t.valid_to, DATE_SUB(( SELECT MIN(t2.valid_from)
                                                FROM taxes t2
                                                WHERE t2.valid_from > t.valid_from
                                                ), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                        ) AS valid_to,
               t.rate
       FROM taxes t 
     ) tax
WHERE valid_from <= {range end date}
AND (valid_to >= {range start date} OR valid_to IS NULL); 

See example

Thanks, that already helps. What do the rules of Stackoverflow provide if something is only a partial solution? The restriction to a given date range is missing.

@root66 to filter on the desired date range you can do: WHERE t1.valid_from <= '2024-12-31' -- End of the desired date range
AND (t1.valid_to >= '2024-01-01' OR t1.valid_to IS NULL); -- Start of the desired date range -> https://dbfiddle.uk/t7Urvcs1

@JoãoGonçalves Does not work for a range from "2024-07-01" to "2024-12-31". It will still return the previous rate.

@root66 see here: https://dbfiddle.uk/KZjtKeGL

@JoãoGonçalves Perfect, thanks!

@root66. I missed the date range filter part. Added the conditions for date range filtering

@ErgestBasha The filter part would return a future date, i.e. in 2025 when valid_to is NULL.

@ErgestBasha if you test the range 2024-01-01 - 2024-12-31, you will notice that the result should be 2 rows, and your answer only has 1 row

I think the date range filters might be the wrong way round here. For example, if you use 2022-07-01 to '2022-11-30', then I expect this should only return the 10% rate that was valid from 2022-01-01 to 2022-12-31. This query returns the 12% and 15% rate, both valid after the input period has ended. It should be valid_from <= {range end}  AND valid_to >= {range start} OR valid_to IS NULL), also take care to include the calculated ``valid_to` and not the value directly from the table.

@JoãoGonçalves , correct, fixed that.

@root66 fixed the filtering part

@GarethD valid_from <= {range end}  AND valid_to >= {range start} OR valid_to IS NULL) , true, I edited the answer

@ErgestBasha now the range 2024-07-01 - 2024-12-31 that should only return 1 row, returns 2, you need to encapsulate everything in a subquery

SELECT `valid_from`, 
       COALESCE(`valid_to`, 
                MIN(`valid_from`) OVER (ORDER BY `valid_from` 
                                        ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING
                                             AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS `valid_to`,
       `rate`
FROM taxes

fiddle
The query assumes that there is no overlapped ranges.
If you need in the output for definite range then select only those rows which overlaps with this range (add proper WHERE).

OVER is MySQL 8 only, need a 5.7 compatible solution.

@root66 for MySQL 5.7 you can do something like:
SELECT t1.valid_from,
COALESCE(
t1.valid_to,
DATE_SUB(
(SELECT MIN(t2.valid_from)
FROM taxes t2
WHERE t2.valid_from > t1.valid_from),
INTERVAL 1 DAY
)
) AS valid_to,
t1.rate
FROM taxes t1;

@root66 need a 5.7 compatible solution Emulate MIN() OVER () with according correlated subquery, this is simple enough. But I'd recommend to upgrade...

When storing ranges that must be continuous and must not overlap (which I assume this is from the problem you describe and your attempted solution), I find that it is better to only store the start date, and have your end date automatically calculated from the next start date (if there is one). This avoids issues where people update a start date but forget to update the corresponding end date, or add a new record and forget to add an end date to the old value.
Also when dealing with date ranges I would always advise to deal with inclusive/exclusive ranges rather than exclusive/exclusive as this way you never get tripped up with datetimes e.g. if you search for what tax rate was applicable as of 2022-12-31 12:00 you may get no match unless you remember to convert the datetime to a date first because this is 12 hours after the 10% rate ended, but 12 hours before the 12% rate starts.
You can combine this logic into a view for ease of access, i.e.
CREATE VIEW taxperiod
AS
SELECT  t.valid_from, 
        ( SELECT MIN(valid_from) 
          FROM taxes AS t2 
          WHERE t2.valid_from > t.valid_from) AS valid_to,
        t.rate
FROM    taxes AS t;

You then don't need to worry about checking for missing end dates because with the new structure this is not possible, meaning your query to check is as simple as:
SELECT *
FROM taxperiod 
WHERE valid_from <= '2024-12-31'
AND  (valid_to > '2022-07-01' OR valid_to IS NULL);

Example on db<>fiddle

Does not work for this given range:
SELECT *
FROM taxperiod
WHERE valid_from < '2024-12-31'
AND  (valid_to >= '2024-07-01' OR valid_to IS NULL)

I think I had the equal to operator on the wrong inequality operator. I've updated the answer. I say think because it is unclear from your feedback of "does not work" exactly what you were expecting to be returned for that date range

When it comes to taxes, you can really assume that they will never end. However, I also use this for other activity data, which then really could end and are not just changed. Thank you for your approach. I just avoid views as much as possible.
